# bunch of if statements as a function and how to call it in swift

Tags: swift

I have a bunch of if statements followed after each other.

I want all these to be checked in a another scenario in which I want these if statements to be called from another if statement. (hope that made sense)

So I figured I need to make all the if statements to a function, and then after my other one if statement it should call this function.

However I can not figure out exactly how to call this function. All the guides I have viewed shows scenarios with printing stuff from the function, but I want all my if statements (I want the whole function to be called)

this is my code of all my if statements:

```
if floatValue3 > 141 && floatValue4 > 70

        {
            star1.hidden = false
            star2.hidden = false
            star3.hidden = false

        }
        if floatValue3 > 160 && floatValue4 > 80 {
            star1.hidden = false
            star2.hidden = false
            star3.hidden = false
            star4.hidden = false

        }

        if floatValue3 > 200 && floatValue4 > 100 {

            star1.hidden = false
            star2.hidden = false
            star3.hidden = false
            star4.hidden = false
            star5.hidden = false

        }

        if floatValue5 > 121 && floatValue6 > 61
        {
            stat2star1.hidden = false
            stat2star2.hidden = false
        }
        if floatValue5 > 141 && floatValue6 > 70

        {
            stat2star1.hidden = false
            stat2star2.hidden = false
            stat2star3.hidden = false

        }
        if floatValue5 > 160 && floatValue6 > 80 {
            stat2star1.hidden = false
            stat2star2.hidden = false
            stat2star3.hidden = false
            stat2star4.hidden = false

        }

        if floatValue5 > 200 && floatValue6 > 100 {

            stat2star1.hidden = false
            stat2star2.hidden = false
            stat2star3.hidden = false
            stat2star4.hidden = false
            stat2star5.hidden = false

            if floatValue > 121 && floatValue2 > 61
            {
                stat3star1.hidden = false
                stat3star2.hidden = false
            }
            if floatValue > 141 && floatValue2 > 70

            {
                stat3star1.hidden = false
                stat3star2.hidden = false
                stat3star3.hidden = false

            }
            if floatValue > 160 && floatValue2 > 80 {
                stat3star1.hidden = false
                stat3star2.hidden = false
                stat3star3.hidden = false
                stat3star4.hidden = false

            }

            if floatValue > 200 && floatValue2 > 100 {

                stat3star1.hidden = false
                stat3star2.hidden = false
                stat3star3.hidden = false
                stat3star4.hidden = false
                stat3star5.hidden = false


            }
```

Comment: this is not wrapped in a function. Wrap it in a function with a name

Answer (score 1):

Those are properties and you're calling it from inside your class correct?

If so just make it a function:

```
func whatever(){
   //all the code
}
```

If you want to call it from outside your class you'll need to pass everything as parameters:

```
func whatever(par: par1, par2: par2){
   //all the code
}
```

And call it normally:

```
whatever()
```

Or:

```
whatever(parameter1, par2)
```